# How to set bytes type to field in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[Supported data types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hEgb.png) I need to insert an image to Firestore as bytes manually but I don't understand how to do this because there is no bytes type. Is it possible?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is not very clear and it might be hard to get a good answer - perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask can give you some hints on how to improve it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Supported data types I need to insert an image to Firestore as bytes manually.

If you need to store an image into a Firestore document, you need to write a byte array type field and **not** simply a byte. Since you didn't specify the programming language you are using, I'll answer it for Android, where you should use Blob's [fromBytes()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Blob#fromBytes%28byte[]%29) method to convert a byte array to a Blob object, then you can pass the `Blob` object to `set()` or `update()` methods. Similarly, you can achieve the same thing in other programming languages too.

This is not highly recommended because there is a [maximum document size of 1 MiB (1,048,576 bytes)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#collections_documents_and_fields) limitation but as long as you stay within this limit for **all** the data the document combined, there won't be any problems. If you want to be safe, you can always check against the max size of a document using the [FirestoreDocument-Android](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirestoreDocument-Android/tree/master/firestore-document) library.