# Proper type to store bytes in Firestore JS

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Serializing fail when storing bytes in firestore as [JS Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Blob) or [Firestore JS Bytes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.bytes):

```
import { Bytes } from "firebase/firestore";

const bin = new Uint8Array([0x48, 0x65, 0x6C, 0x6C, 0x6F]);

// Convert the binary data to a JS Blob Or FirestoreJS Bytes
const jsBlob = new Blob([bin]);
const fsBytes = Bytes.fromUint8Array(bin);

db.collection('your_collection').doc('your_document').set({
  binaryData: jsBlob
  // binaryData: fsBytes
});
```

Using [Js Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Blob):

> Error: Value for argument "data" is not a valid Firestore document. Input is not a plain JavaScript object (found in field "binaryData").

Using [Firestore Bytes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.bytes):

> Error: Value for argument "data" is not a valid Firestore document. Couldn't serialize object of type "Bytes" (found in field "binaryData"). Firestore doesn't support JavaScript objects with custom prototypes (i.e. objects that were created via the "new" operator).

- [Others Questions using Android SDK mention to use Blob](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61246654/954853)
- [Some sources mentions a Blob type in firestore js but cant find it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53672081/954853)

Comment: Using Uint8Array works, but the value is then displayed as a base64 string in firestore emulator?

Comment: When you wrote `Bytes.fromUint8Array(binaryData)`, did you mean `bin` instead?  You aren't showing what `binaryData` is.  Please edit the question to provide code that we can easily copy and paste.  Also you can remove the parts of your question that aren't relevant (like the renaming of Blob to Bytes).  Just make your question say what you want without worry about retaining the history.  SO keeps a history of the question for you.

Comment: @DougStevenson Sorry missed 2 renames.
For renaming part i thought this was relevant for whoever may get accross the same question and not understant why should they rather pick one or another..? But remove it if it's against SO quidelines.

Comment: It's a whole lot easier if you just show the code you're using that doesn't work the way you expect, and make it easy to copy and paste that so the result can be reproduced easily.  If the reader doesn't know what you're doing, then they're not likely to give you an answer, right?

Answer (score 0):

**[Temporary answer, need clarification]**

```
const bin = new Uint8Array([0x48, 0x65, 0x6C, 0x6C, 0x6F]);

db.collection('your_collection').doc('your_document').set({
  binaryData: bin
});
```

- Firebase Admin SDK seems to not support its own Bytes as Firebase Web
  SDK does.
- Uint8Array seems the way to go for Firebase Admin SDK.